# changing stroke-opacity of <svg> object's path

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

In short - I am trying to change the stroke-opacity of a path within an  by hovering over one of the titles to the left (you'll see the 'presidio' title has a link to it)
none of the JQuery/javascript answers I've seen so far are working.

the latest snippet I've tried is:

```
d3.select('.presidio').on('mouseover', function(){
  console.log('hey!');
  var object = document.getElementById("presidio");
  object.setAttribute("stroke-opacity", 1);
});
```

the svg is huge so pasting it here would take a million years to read. but if you care to inspect the svg element here: http://www.petegetscreative.com/hoods/hoods.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the opacity of an element with id 'presidio:

```
d3.select('#presidio').style("stroke-opacity", "1");
```

To add a mouse over effect to all elements with the class 'presidio'

```
d3.selectAll('.presidio').on('mouseover', function(){
  d3.select(this).style("stroke-opacity", "1"); })
```

Comment: I actually found a very similar solution right about the time you answered with this :p I did it by doing this within the mouseover function: $('#mySVG').find("path.port").css('stroke-opacity', "1");

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but have you tried:

```
object.setAttribute("stroke-opacity", "1");
```

I thought having the quotes was proper syntax.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use either quote type as long as it's consistent, either way it shows up as TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'object.setAttribute') in the console. But not having the quotes around the 1 was a syntactical error on my part I think.

Comment: Again, I was just checking to see if maybe that small change would fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this...

```js
object.style['stroke-opacity'] = 1;
```